# Error al Sobrecargar el operador <<

Tags: c++, clase, sobrecarga-de-operadores

Hace poco estuve viendo operadores sobrecargados y he entendido relativamente bien el tema pero me han pedido sobrecargar el operador `<<` y en dicho código utilizamos la clase :

```
#define _COMPLEJO_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complejo
{
private:
  float Real;
  float Img;
public:
  Complejo(float R=0, float I=0);
  ~Complejo(){};
  void ImprimirComplejo();
  Complejo Complejo::operator +(Complejo z2);
  Complejo Complejo::operator -(Complejo z2);
  Complejo Complejo::operator *(Complejo z2);
  ostream &operator << (ostream &os, const Complejo &z);
};
```

Pero al tratar de hacer la sobrecarga del operador `<<` con la funcion `ostream &operator << (ostream &os, const Complejo &z);`
esta me tira el siguiente error:

`std::ostream& Complejo::operator<<(std::ostream&, const`

y el el main que es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "complejo.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{

 Complejo z1(3,1), z2(1,2), z3;
 z3=z1+z2;
 cout<<endl<<endl<<"El resultado de la SUMA de números complejos es: "<<endl;
 z3.ImprimirComplejo();
 z3=z1-z2;
 cout<<endl<<endl<<"El resultado de la RESTA de números complejos es: "<<endl;
 z3.ImprimirComplejo();
 cout<<endl<<endl<<"El resultado de la MULTIPLICACION de numeros complejos es: "<<endl;
 z3=z1*z2;

 cout<<z3;

 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}
```

me da el siguiente error: 
`no match for std::ostream& << Complejo&' operator`

Tambien tengo el cpp donde declaro las funciones:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "complejo.h"
using namespace std;
Complejo::Complejo(float R, float I){
    Real= R;
    Img= I;
}
void Complejo::ImprimirComplejo(){
    cout<<"La componente en real del número comlejo es:"<< Real<<endl;
    cout<<"La componente en imaginario del número comlejo es:"<< Img<<endl;
}
Complejo Complejo::operator +(Complejo Z2){ 
    return Complejo(Real+Z2.Real,Img+Z2.Img);
}
Complejo Complejo::operator -(Complejo Z2){ 
    return Complejo(Real-Z2.Real,Img-Z2.Img);
}
Complejo Complejo::operator *(Complejo z2){
    return Complejo((Real*z2.Real)-(Img*z2.Img),(Real*z2.Img)-(Img*z2.Real));
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Complejo &z)
{
  return (os << z.Real << '/' << z.Img);
}
```

pero acá no me da ningún error.

En fin yo quisiera saber cual es el motivo de este error ya que según lo que he estudiado la declaración de la sobrecarga esta bien y no entiendo porque me tira ese error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacer que el operador sea amigo de tu clase:

```
class Complejo
{
    float Real;
    float Img;
public:
    Complejo(float R=0, float I=0);
    ~Complejo(){};
    void ImprimirComplejo();
    Complejo Complejo::operator +(Complejo z2);
    Complejo Complejo::operator -(Complejo z2);
    Complejo Complejo::operator *(Complejo z2);
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &, const Complejo &);
 // ~~~~~~ <---- Función amiga
};
```

Y definir la función (como ya has hecho en el archivo de código):

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Complejo &z)
{
    return (os << z.Real << '/' << z.Img);
}
```

Comment: Gracias bro! y disculpa por la pregunta tonta pero tengo el mejor maestro del mundo XD